# Rails validate minimum no. of associated object in case of nested form and allow_destroy: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am using nested for for user has many images, when user remove the image then 
`validates :images, :length => { :minimum => 1}`
does not work.

It checks only if the images are blank only for new form, but in edit form if images are already present and we remove the image with "link_to remove" then the validation does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User 
  has_many :images, autosave: true
end
```

When [autosave](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#label-One-to-many+Example) is true all children are saved, no matter whether they are new records or not.

You may also like to check out [association callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks).